# java linked list pass by reference does not work

Tags: java, linked-list

I am writing a function to find the intersection of two linked list.

My first implementation was like this (advanceByK function advances and does not return value):

```
public ListNode getIntersectionNode(ListNode a, ListNode b) {

        int aLen=findLength(a);
        int bLen = findLength(b);

        if(aLen==0 || bLen==0) return null;

        ListNode aTemp = a, bTemp = b;

        if(aLen>bLen) {
            advanceByK(aTemp,aLen-bLen);
        } else if(bLen > aLen) {
            advanceByK(bTemp,bLen-aLen);
        }

        while((aTemp!=null) && (bTemp !=null)) {
            if(aTemp.equals(bTemp))return aTemp;

            aTemp = aTemp.next;
            bTemp = bTemp.next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void advanceByK(ListNode head, int k) {

        while(k>0) {
            if(head!=null) head=head.next;
            k--;
        }
    }

    public int findLength(ListNode head) {
        ListNode temp = head;
        int res =0;
        if(temp==null) return res;

        while(temp!=null) {
            res++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        return res;
    }
```

And then I changed to this and it worked

```
    public ListNode advanceByK(ListNode head, int k) {

        while(k>0) {
            if(head!=null) head=head.next;
            k--;
        }
        return head;
    }
```

What I am doing wrong here?

I know that Java pass by reference, and it should have moved the head in the advanceByK function

Comment: "I know that Java pass by reference" it's not.

Answer (score 1):

In your first implementation, `head` is a reference to a specific `ListNode` object.  If you were to make modifications to `head` by calling methods on it, it would behave in the way you would expect for something being passed by reference.

However, what you did instead was this:

```
head=head.next;
```

That doesn't modify any state in the object referenced by `head`.  Instead, it changes which `ListNode` the local `head` variable is pointing to.  The original `ListNode` pointed to by `head` is left unchanged.